# Can't see why error is MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make login form in Laravel 4.2 + Sentry . The problem is that when I submit the form I got the error that method is not allowed.

When I check my form in source it has `method="POST"` and also in the route I've wrote `post`. What can be the problem?

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

but can't see why? This is the form

```
        {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'check-auth')) }}
            <div class="body bg-gray">
                {{-- Display flash message --}}
                @if (Session::has('flash_message'))
                    <span style="margin-left:18%; color: #ff0000">{{ Session::get('flash_message') }}</span>
                @endif

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="User email"/>
                    @if($errors->has('login_errors')) <span class="has-error">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span> @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="User password"/>
                </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submitbtn" class="btn bg-olive btn-block">Sign me in</button>  
            </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

Route

```
Route::post('user-login', ['as'=>'check-auth', 'uses'=>'AuthenticationController@login']);
```

and controller

```
public function login()
{
    try{
        $credentials = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')

        );

        $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
        if($user){
            return Redirect::to('dashboard');
        }

        return Redirect::to('/')->with('title','Login errors');
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        Session::flash('flash_message', 'No access!');
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('title','Login errors');
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Error

```
production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException in /var/www/html/time/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:210
```

Comment: It might be helpful to show us the exception too.

Comment: @Chris I've updated the question. This is what I see only..

Comment: Given the code you provided, I don't see any issues. You'll have to post more code and as @Chris said, show the whole exception.

Comment: You probably have but can you check over the basics. Correct machine (I notice the error says production), any nesting to the routes with prefixes, try redefining the route as GET and die() with some message at the top of the route action in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're route is correct, the only thing I could suggest would be to append the type to the opening of the form:
`{{ Form::open(['url' => 'check-auth', 'method' => 'post']) }}`

Comment: Thanks, this works but I can't understand why this works but other one didn't .. since they're same?

Comment: I believe it add's another hidden field to the form, at least it does in L5 using the package, been a while since I've used Laravel 4. @VLS

Answer (score 1):

{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'check-auth')) }}

See, You are using route check-auth and in routes file you defined a different route i.e **user-login**

```
Route::post('user-login', ['as'=>'check-auth', 'uses'=>'AuthenticationController@login']);
```

Correct route and try again this will work

Comment: `check-auth` is the name of the route and should work with the form as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of post use get (it can still post things but your are able to retrieve too)